# Which variable should be optimize in following C code

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-optimization

If your compiler actually optimizes access time of only two registers variables per function, which two variable in the following program are the best one to be made into register variables?

```
void main(void)
{
  int i,j,k,m;
  do
  {
    printf("enter value");
    scanf(“%d”,&i);
    m=0;
    for(k=0;k<100;k++)
      m=k+m;
  }
  while(i>0);
}
```

Please ignore if any mistake is there...

Comment: how hard is it to spell out "your", "the", "are"... ?

Comment: Please don't "optimize" words in natural language.

Comment: Also, I can't simply ignore the `void main` mistake.

Comment: It must be nice to have people do your homework for you. But really, AMIT, on the difficulty scale, this question ranks about -1.

Comment: yaa i know its not difficult but @Jim i wanna to know whtat experts says...nd i don't want people to do my homework..

Comment: Is it possible you are in a class, being told about compiler optimizations, but not being told that in a program like this, outside of `scanf` time, 99.999<some number of 9s>99% of the time is in `printf` ??

Comment: NO one has taught us about optimazations...

Comment: @AMIT Where did the question and the code come from? Because it gives a strong appearance that the person who crafted it already knows the answer.

Comment: @Cody The `main` method can return `void` in freestanding implementations. In any case, that isn't germane to the question -- it certainly isn't "more important" in this context, so in a very strong sense, **you** don't know what you're doing. Pretend that the function isn't named `main` and that the OP wrote "function" or "routine" instead of "program" and stop engaging in such **foolish** pedantry.

Comment: @Jim am preparing some question for interview ,and in one book i read it and its without answer ....

Comment: @AMIT You would benefit a lot more, and be better received, if you would say what you think is correct and why, not just ask for answers.

Comment: ThanKS @Jim ,got your point .....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly not `j`, since it is never used. Not `i` either, as you are using the address-of operator to write to it, which means it needs to be read back from memory after it's been written by the `scanf`. That only leaves `k` and `m`.

Comment: Some of the "answers" talk about optimizing away the calculation of `m`, but that simply doesn't answer the question, which does not state one way or the other whether the compiler does such optimizations, it only asks which variables would it be *best* to put into registers. The question is a bit silly because it's so easy to answer, but it does test some rudimentary skills, including the ability to comprehend questions.

Comment: @Jim: It seems just as silly to assume that the compiler will perform *some* of the obvious optimizations, but not others. The answer that `j`, `k`, and `m` should be optimized away is completely correct. I just can't understand how that fails to answer the question. When you ask contrived questions like this one, the answer may not be quite as you expect. That doesn't make it any less correct. Jonathan's answer is correct as far as it goes, but it doesn't go far enough!

Answer (score 5):

Trick question? In a smart compiler, none of the variables are registerized. `i` has its address taken, so it can't be in a register all the time. `j`, `k` and `m` should be optimized away.

Answer (score 3):

Good compiler will optimize this part of code:

```
m=0;
for(k=0;k<100;k++)
  m=k+m;
```

And replaced it with `m = 4950;` :) 
The better one will optimize `m = 4950;` and put nothing in place). j also will be optimized. And `i` can't be register because in `scanf` its address is needed. So final answer is "NO ONE".

Comment: You cannot put `i` into a register, as `scanf` is being passed the address of it.

Comment: If you agree then you know you're answer is wrong and you should either delete it or edit it to be correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess the compiler would pick k and m

Comment: This answer would be a lot more useful if you provided some justification or basis for your guess.

Comment: yes yes yes ... my rule of thumb is to assume inner most variables are most benefical to optimize (hence my answer).  but I know life is far from that simple ... eg I know some compiles may optimize the inner with m=5950 (like somebody else said)

Comment: Why do people upvote such poor answers? a) If you have to guess, you should let people who *don't* have to guess give the answer. b) You clearly put no time or thought into this, because k and m are the only possible answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since the result of the computation is never used the compiler can optimize out almost all of your code. The only things that must remain are equivalent to

```
int main(void) {
  int i;
  do {
    printf("enter value");
    scanf(“%d”,&i);
  } while(i>0);
  return 0;
}
```

As others have already said the only remaining variable `i` can't be of `register` storage class since its address is taken.